# Sanity check whether my SQLAlchemy class and query is functionally equivalent to a raw SQL statement

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

New to SQLALchemy, and this is my attempt at recreating this query:

```
SELECT
          database_server_id || 'dr' database_server_id
        , CASE
            WHEN database_server_id LIKE 'cluster1' AND name IS NULL THEN 'canvas'
            WHEN database_server_id LIKE 'cluster4' AND name IS NULL THEN 'canvas'
            WHEN name IS NULL THEN database_server_id
            ELSE name
          END AS database_name
          ,SUBSTRING(database_server_id FROM '\d+$')::INT cluster_id
          ,CASE
            WHEN name IS NULL THEN SUBSTRING(database_server_id FROM '\d+$')::INT
            ELSE SUBSTRING(name FROM '\d+$')::INT
          END AS shard_id
        FROM canvas.switchman_shards
        WHERE database_server_id LIKE 'cluster%'
        ORDER BY cluster_id, shard_id
```

I've used declarative to create the class, and then used `hybrid_properties` to take care of the additional logic.  Let me know what errors I have made!

```
class SwitchmanShards(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'switchman_shards'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    database_server_id = Column(String)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    default = Column(Boolean)
    settings = Column(String)
    delayed_jobs_shard_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

    def __init__(self,
                 id,
                 db_server_id,
                 name,
                 default,
                 settings,
                 del_job_shard_id):
        self.id = id
        self.database_server_id = db_server_id
        self.name = name
        self.default = default
        self.settings = settings
        self.delayed_jobs_shard_id = del_job_shard_id

    @hybrid_property
    def cluster_id(self):
        # Clusters that do not use their cluster name as the schema and need to
        # be recast.
        cluster_list = ('cluster1dr', 'cluster4dr')
        if self.database_server_id in cluster_list and self.name is None:
            return 'canvas'
        elif self.name is None:
            return self.database_server_id
        else:
            return self.name

    @hybrid_property
    def shard_id(self):
        shard_regex = re.compile(r'(\d+$)')
        if self.name is None:
            res = shard_regex.search(self.database_server_id)
            return res.group(1)
        else:
            res = shard_regex.search(self.name)
            return res.group(1)



def return_shards():
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    shards = session.query(SwitchmanShards).filter(
        SwitchmanShards.database_server_id.like('cluster%')
    ).all()
    return shards
```

As a side note, I'm trying to figure out the value of SQLALchemy due to the fact that it took me about 3 times as many lines to write the same code.  Arguably it is more readable, that's the big plus I can see.

EDIT: I've noticed that this brings in 10 less records than the raw SQL query, not sure why this is.

Comment: You shouldn't provide `__init__` to a declarative model class the way you do (read: at all). Best case: it's just unnecessary, worst case: you break stuff.

Comment: You're also comparing apples and oranges. The declarative model class is more akin to `CREATE TABLE`, with python goodies on top. The value will become obvious if you ever have to transition (short) code between different databases, since SQLA handles most of the differences pretty transparently, esp. if you're not using stuff from the `dialect` modules. Transitioning will always be a pain though, even with SQLA (migrating data etc.). Another valuable property of SQLA is the ability to create small reusable functions that alter queries without string parsing.

Comment: I know that the previous comment reads like a fanboy defending his precious library, but the composability truly is a god send. As to why the SQLA version of the query returns less rows, could you provide sample data to play with? The queries do seem pretty much the same, at least as far as the predicates go.

Comment: Your `cluster_id` looks significantly different and you're missing `database_name`.